# How to clear the contents under /run/user/1000/doc?

Tags: tmpfs, flatpak, sandbox

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and installed `evince` via `flatpak`, when I open `evince`, it usually makes a copy of the opened file into `/run/user/1000/doc`. I learned that `/run/user/1000/doc` is the temporary directory for storing file used by running applications, but when I quit evince the files created by it does not go away. Even if I reboot my machine the files still exist. As the directory cannot be accessed in usual way (it is not writable and cannot be changed with `chmod`), how can I remove the contents in `/run/user/1000/doc`?